# EMF from power lines

Tags: emf

My new house flat is near an overhead power line. It's a steel structure so it's the higher energy lines. The line is about 1200 feet away at the closest point, I guess that is fairly far and you'll never know if you're ever under an electric cable. How safe is this?

The land the flat is on is 20 meters higher.

How safe is this?

Comment: @Tom this should be an answer; please say "here's the graphic from LINK, and the German limit, which was confirmed by large medical studies is 500 µT, so you're below that by a factor of FACTOR". We get these FUD questions once in a while, and it's best to either close them or quickly give the facts and move on.

Answer (score 3):

Thats about 360 m away from the power line? It depends decisively on which voltage is carried, but at this distance, I personally wouldn't worry about EMF. There is a scheme, where you see the distance in meters from the power line: http://www.bfs.de/EN/topics/emf/expansion-grid/basics/field-strain/field-strain_node.html

For a 380 kV line:

[image: figure from the link above]

The federal law in Germany permits 500 µT as limit after extensive studies, so you're far, far, far below anything risky.

Comment: the link is broken